# Spinner setOnItemSelectedListener Doesn't Fire

Tags: android, spinner

I have a view object that contains a edittext, an invisible spinner, and a button.  I load the view via the LayoutInflater and it shows up and everything works fine.  I hit the button, the spinner list shows up and I select the item that I want.  My problem is that the setOnItemSelectedListener for the spinner doesn't fire so I can't set the edittext to the selected value.

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,                           android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listItems);
                                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

```
                        Spinner spn = (Spinner)sEdit.findViewWithTag("spn"+fieldID);
                        final String spnHolder = "spn"+fieldID;

                        spn.setAdapter(adapter);
                        ImageButton bSpn = (ImageButton)sEdit.findViewWithTag("btn"+fieldID);
                        bSpn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                curVw = (EditText)sEdit.findViewWithTag(v.getTag().toString().split("btn")[1]);
                                ((Spinner)sEdit.findViewWithTag(spnHolder)).performClick();
                            }

                        });

                        try {
                            spn.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                                    curVw.setText(((TextView)arg1).getText().toString());
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }
                            });
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex) 
                        {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

I added a Try...Catch to see if it was just failing past that point, but it is never called.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are passing a spinner without a listener to your button onclick. Try moving spn.setOnItemSelectedListener before bSpn.setOnClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `SetOnclickListener` please use:

```
spn.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

   //implements methods and perform your action. This will works definately
};
```